# "many numbers to describe the proof of the fact that A is isomorphic to itself"

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

In "conceptual mathematics" by Lawvere et al., it says on page 107:

> The expression 'each set is number' refers to the attitude toward sets in general 
>   whereby we consider relationships like $\cong$ or $\leq_R$ , but don't worry about the details of 
>   the particular 'proofs,' f and $f^{-1}$ or r and s, of these relationships. One shouldn't 
>   always neglect these; *we'll see later that a given proof that A has the same number as 
>   itself (an automorphism of A) is a rich structure that needs many numbers to 
>   describe it.*

What do the authors mean with "is a rich structure that needs many numbers to 
describe it"? To which "later page" in the book do they refer, that is, on which page do we see that

> a given proof that A has the same number as 
>   itself (an automorphism of A) is a rich structure that needs many numbers to 
>   describe it
>   ?

Comment: I think they just mean that $A$ has more than one automorphism, so you have to give additional information if you want to specify a particular automorphism.

Comment: This is asked also on MathOverflow: [“many numbers to describe the proof of the fact that A is isomorphic to itself”](https://mathoverflow.net/q/272769). Basic info about cross-posting is [collected here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info).